# Vertically align two labels and inputs in a div

Tags: css

I have a `div` with two `labels`, and two `inputs`, and I need two vertically align them without making two `divs`. I want to vertically align the inputs and labels in `css` so that they are on top of each other.

```html
<div id="name">
    <label for="Fname">First Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="Fname" id="Fname" placeholder="First Name" maxlength="15" required>

    <label for="Lname">Last Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="Lname" id="Lname" placeholder="Last Name" maxlength="20" required>
</div>
```

I have tried `vertical-align` in css but that did not work.
can you help?

Comment: Please see [ask]. You're expected to make an attempt and show your code. Also, this question has been asked many times already.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox) layout in your CSS file.

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `flex` and `flex-col` property in your html div

```
<div class="display: flex; flex-direction: column">
  <label for="Lname">Last Name:</label>
  <input
    type="text"
    name="Lname"
    id="Lname"
    placeholder="Last Name"
    maxlength="20"
    required
  />
</div>
```

[image]